# angular bootstrap dialog never opens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've got the following code:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('modalClickItemController', function ($scope, $dialog) {

$scope.openDialog = function(opts){
    console.debug('bar');
    var d = $dialog.dialog(opts);
    d.open().then(function(result){
        console.debug('foobarbazz');
    });
}

});
```

This is used in a directive like so:

```
 angular.module('myApp')
.directive('modalClickItem', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'modalClickItemController',
        link: function postLink(scope, el, attr){
            scope.objectId = attr.objectId;
            scope.objectType = attr.objectType
            scope.opts = {
                backdrop: true,
                keyboard: true,
                backdropClick: true,
                template: "<div class='modal-header'>Hi!!!</div><div class='modal-body'>Buy!!!</div>",
  //                    templateUrl:  'views/'+scope.objectType+'_modal.html',
                controller: 'modalCtrl'
            }

            el.on('click', function(){
                scope.openDialog(scope.opts);

            });
        }
    };
});
```

This code prints bar, however it never prints foobarbazz. If I stick debugs into angular bootstrap, it goes into the open method, and returns the promise, but never opens the dialog.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tNokVEbRds78tBaVZtLH?p=preview

Why?

Comment: afaik your "open promise" will be resolved when the dialog is closed:
d.open().then(function(result){
      if(result)
      {
        alert('dialog closed with result: ' + result);
      }
    });

where is your modalCtrl?

Answer (score 0):

I use [jquery.bootstrap.js](https://github.com/newghost/bootstrap-jquery-plugin/) , it's very small and simple, similar with easyui.

```
$("#loginwrap").dialog({
      title:    "Login"
    , buttons: [
        {
            text: "Close"
          , classed: "btn-primary"
          , click: function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Login"
          , classed: "btn-success"
          , click: function() {
              //your login handler

              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
      ]
});
```